# Efficient SVD of low-rank matrix of the form $C=AB^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Let $A,B$ be two real matrices, of dimensions $n \times k$ and $m \times k$, respectively. I assume that $k \ll n,m$.

I am interested in computing the SVD of the product matrix $C = AB^{T}$. The matrix $C$ is large, of dimensions $n \times m$, and it is slow to deal with (computationally speaking). Is there a way to exploit knowledge of the factors $A,B$, to compute efficiently the SVD of $C$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1837527/10063, though the answer there seems incomplete and the question is somewhat different since they assume to know the SVDs of the factors, which I don't necessarily know here. Thus my question is more general.

Comment: Maybe first compute the QR decomps of $A,B$ and then deal with the middle $n\times m$ matrix later, which is a sparse product of upper and lower triangular matrices?

Comment: Without further assumptions on the setup / what the computational environment is / etc., I think @V.S.e.H.'s suggestions is basically optimal (but the middle matrix is $k\times k$). Computing $n\times k$ and $m\times k$ matrices with orthogonal columns will take $\sim (m+n)k^2$ flops no matter what. And assuming $k$ is small even a $k^3$ cost to do dense linear algebra on the middle matrix is fine.

Comment: @overfullhbox It's not $k\times k$, but it is an $n\times m$ of the form $\begin{pmatrix}D &0\\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ where $D$ is $k\times k$. Usually numerical packages do trim the zeros though.

Comment: Won't the QR factorization of a $n\times k$ matrix give you a $n\times k$ Q and a $k\times k$ R? And similarly for $B$

Comment: @overfullhbox If $Q$ was not square, then it wouldn't be orthogonal/unitary, would it? But don't take my word for it, consult your favorite numerical package. I use Julia, and `qr` gives me an $n\times n$ and a $k\times k$, but it trimmed the zeros off the triangular matrix.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it depends on how you define the QR factorization; it could just return a matrix with orthonormal columns (for instance, this is what numpy would do by default).